# Unable to connect to fresh server

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I am miffed... To say the least

I can't connect to my server via any means:

```
ufw disable
root@server~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
```

And yet I still cannot ping the server.

This is a fresh install with a fresh Apache running Ubuntu 12.04 :/

Any thoughts?

Comment: Of course I can ssh via the ip :)

Comment: So you are able to SSH in but not ping the same IP from the machine you're connecting from, right?

Comment: Exactly, ssh to my hearts content :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

and

```
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

which is a bit confusing.

The recommended practice is to set the default policy to **DROP** and then to accept the traffic you need.

Ping does not work because you haven't allowed it.

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Delete all existing rules
iptables -F

# Set default chain policies
iptables -P INPUT DROP

# allow established/related
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# allow ssh
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT

# allow http
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j ACCEPT

# pings
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
```

Make it executable and run it.

Then consider if you need some rules for your `OUTPUT` and `FORWARD` chains.

For more information check out the [Official Ubuntu iptables howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo).

Comment: Genius... I'm confused to why iptables is set up like that out of the box. Maybe the image fasthosts use does that